# Does anyone know if it is possible to create an ipad app that can be an airplay receiver?

Tags: ipad, ios5, airplay, ipad-2

can anyone point to any ios library or developer documentation that would help me accomplish the following:

I would like to build an app that can be the receiver of another ios device using airplay mirroring.

Is this possible? allowed by apple?

Answer (score 0):

That would be annoying to program and Apple would most likely reject it, since you may need to license with them in order to set up an AirPlay utility.